# python selenium grid desired_capabilities TypeError

Tags: python, typeerror, selenium-grid, desiredcapabilities

I'm trying to do cross browser test with selenium grid and when I typing webdrive.Remote(command_executor, desired_capabilities) it shows me that  desired_capabilities is Unexpected argument and when i run my test it's give my a  TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'desired_capabilities'

Here is my  fixture:

@pytest.fixture(params=["chrome", "firefox", "edge"])
def driver_initialization(request):
"""
Initiate Driver for Selenium Grid on LambdaTest
:param request:
"""

```
desired_caps = {}
if request.param == "chrome":
    desired_caps.update(chrome_cap)
    driver = webdriver.Remote(
        command_executor=RemoteConnection(remote_url),
        desired_capabilities={"LT: Options": desired_caps} #yelow highlight with "Unexpected argument" warning
    )
elif request.param == "firefox":
    desired_caps.update(firefox_cap)
    driver = webdriver.Remote(
        command_executor=RemoteConnection(remote_url),
        desired_capabilities={"LT: Options": desired_caps} #yelow highlight with "Unexpected argument" warning
    )
elif request.param == "edge":
    desired_caps.update(edge_cap)
    driver = webdriver.Remote(
        command_executor=RemoteConnection(remote_url),
        desired_capabilities={"LT: Options": desired_caps} #yelow highlight with "Unexpected argument" warning
    )
request.cls.driver = driver
yield
driver.close()
```

Can anyone helm me with that?
Thank you all in advance!